# How to get rid of Community Toolbar in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari

Every time I start Safari or Finder an error appears:

> We're sorry, but the Safari browser version you are currently using does not support the community toolbar.

How do I delete this toolbar? Other forums suggest deleting it from the "toolbar" folder, but there is no such folder in my Applications folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have "infected" multiple locations in */Library*. First, quit Safari. Might not hurt to also run the following command from a Terminal (it will prompt you for your password):

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.conduit.loader.agent.plist
```

Then, delete the following files/folders by moving them to Trash and emptying it.

Note that */* is your Macintosh HD, and the *Library* folder might be invisible. To access it, press <kbd>⌘⇧G</kbd> in a Finder window and enter `/Library`.

```
/Library/Application Support/Conduit
/Library/InputManagers/CTLoader
/Library/Receipts/ctloader.pkg
/Library/Receipts/<Toolbar name>.pkg
/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/CT2285220.bundle
/Users/<User name>/Library/Application Support/Conduit
```

That should be it, according to [forum posts](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2179391?start=0&tstart=0) and this [cnet.com article](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20027867-263.html).